# Null pointer exception after releasing the app to google play

Tags: android, kotlin, null, google-play

I sent my app to google play so it can be reviewed and published, But now I got a weird null pointer error on firebase from a java adapter file, And I am sure the file is written in kotlin, How can I fix this?

Firebase error Log:

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String java.lang.String.trim()' on a null object reference
   at sun.misc.FloatingDecimal.readJavaFormatString(FloatingDecimal.java:1838)
   at sun.misc.FloatingDecimal.parseDouble(FloatingDecimal.java:110)
   at java.lang.Double.parseDouble(Double.java:538)
   at com.yousefelsayed.gamescheap.adapter.SteamEpicGamesRecyclerAdapter.onBindViewHolder(SteamEpicGamesRecyclerAdapter.java:212)
   at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.java:1198)
   at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.tryBindViewHolderByDeadline(RecyclerView.java:1198)
   at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.tryGetViewHolderForPositionByDeadline(RecyclerView.java:1198)
   at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:59)
   at androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager$LayoutState.next(LinearLayoutManager.java:59)
   at androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager.P0(LinearLayoutManager.java:1)
   at androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager.fill(LinearLayoutManager.java:54)
   at androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager.onLayoutChildren(LinearLayoutManager.java:958)
   at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.q(RecyclerView.java:39)
   at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.onMeasure(RecyclerView.java:64)
   at android.view.View.measure(View.java:23221)
   at androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout$Measurer.measure(ConstraintLayout.java:543)
   at androidx.constraintlayout.core.widgets.analyzer.BasicMeasure.measure(BasicMeasure.java:99)
   at androidx.constraintlayout.core.widgets.analyzer.BasicMeasure.measureChildren(BasicMeasure.java:1366)
   at androidx.constraintlayout.core.widgets.ConstraintWidgetContainer.measure(ConstraintWidgetContainer.java:1366)
   at androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout.resolveSystem(ConstraintLayout.java:1366)
   at androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout.onMeasure(ConstraintLayout.java:530)
   at android.view.View.measure(View.java:23221)
   at androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView.measureChildWithMargins(NestedScrollView.java:38)
   at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:185)
   at androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView.onMeasure(NestedScrollView.java)
   at android.view.View.measure(View.java:23221)
   at androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout$Measurer.measure(ConstraintLayout.java:543)
   at androidx.constraintlayout.core.widgets.analyzer.BasicMeasure.measure(BasicMeasure.java:99)
   at androidx.constraintlayout.core.widgets.analyzer.BasicMeasure.measureChildren(BasicMeasure.java:1366)
   at androidx.constraintlayout.core.widgets.ConstraintWidgetContainer.measure(ConstraintWidgetContainer.java:1366)
   at androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout.resolveSystem(ConstraintLayout.java:1366)
   at androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout.onMeasure(ConstraintLayout.java:530)
   at android.view.View.measure(View.java:23221)
   at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6749)
   at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:185)
   at android.view.View.measure(View.java:23221)
   at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6749)
   at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:185)
   at android.view.View.measure(View.java:23221)
   at androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout$Measurer.measure(ConstraintLayout.java:543)
   at androidx.constraintlayout.core.widgets.ConstraintWidgetContainer.measure(ConstraintWidgetContainer.java:253)
   at androidx.constraintlayout.core.widgets.ConstraintWidgetContainer.layout(ConstraintWidgetContainer.java:46)
   at androidx.constraintlayout.core.widgets.analyzer.BasicMeasure.solveLinearSystem(BasicMeasure.java:30)
   at androidx.constraintlayout.core.widgets.analyzer.BasicMeasure.solverMeasure(BasicMeasure.java:1511)
   at androidx.constraintlayout.core.widgets.ConstraintWidgetContainer.measure(ConstraintWidgetContainer.java:1511)
   at androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout.resolveSystem(ConstraintLayout.java:1511)
   at androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout.onMeasure(ConstraintLayout.java:530)
   at android.view.View.measure(View.java:23221)
   at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6749)
   at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:185)
   at androidx.appcompat.widget.ContentFrameLayout.onMeasure(ContentFrameLayout.java:154)
   at android.view.View.measure(View.java:23221)
   at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6749)
   at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1535)
   at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:825)
   at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:704)
   at android.view.View.measure(View.java:23221)
   at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6749)
   at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:185)
   at android.view.View.measure(View.java:23221)
   at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6749)
   at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1535)
   at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:825)
   at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:704)
   at android.view.View.measure(View.java:23221)
   at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6749)
   at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:185)
   at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.onMeasure(DecorView.java:716)
   at android.view.View.measure(View.java:23221)
   at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:2738)
   at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1591)
   at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1875)
   at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1479)
   at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:7280)
   at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:1012)
   at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:823)
   at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:758)
   at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:998)
   at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873)
   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6846)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
   at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:883)
```

The error says that it happens on line 212 but the kotlin file is 65 lines

Main file OnBindViewHolder:

```
override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {
    val itemViewModel = mList[position]
    holder.layout.doOnLayout {
        Glide.with(holder.gameImage)
            .load(itemViewModel.image)
            .apply(RequestOptions().override(holder.layout.width,holder.layout.height))
            .skipMemoryCache(true)
            .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.AUTOMATIC)
            .format(DecodeFormat.PREFER_ARGB_8888)
            .placeholder(R.color.imageLoadingColor)
            .error(R.drawable.no_image_found)
            .into(holder.gameImage)
    }
    holder.gameImage.setImageDrawable(null)
    holder.gameTitle.text = itemViewModel.title
    if (itemViewModel.x == "0.00") holder.gameCurrent.text = holder.itemView.context.getString(R.string.Free_String)
    else holder.gameCurrent.text = holder.itemView.context.getString(R.string.xText,itemViewModel.x)
    holder.gameOld.text = holder.itemView.context.getString(R.string.xText,itemViewModel.y)
    holder.gameOld.paintFlags = holder.gameOld.paintFlags or Paint.STRIKE_THRU_TEXT_FLAG
    val percentage = (itemViewModel.x.toDouble() / itemViewModel.y.toDouble()) * 100
    if (percentage.toString() == "0.0") holder.gamePercentage.text = holder.itemView.context.getString(R.string.hundred_percent)
    else holder.gamePercentage.text = holder.itemView.context.getString(R.string.percentageText,percentage.toInt().toString())
}
```

The ViewModel

```
data class SteamAndEpicGamesViewModel(private val steamAndEpicGamesRepository: SteamAndEpicGamesRepository): ViewModel(){

private val errorHandler = CoroutineExceptionHandler{_,t ->
    run{
        requestStatus.postValue(t.message.toString())
    }
}
fun startSteamEpicGamesRequest(){
    viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO+errorHandler) {
        steamAndEpicGamesRepository.getSteamAndEpicGames()
    }
}

val games: LiveData<Games> get() = steamAndEpicGamesRepository.games
val requestStatus = steamAndEpicGamesRepository.requestStatus
}
```

ViewModel Factory

```
class SteamAndEpicGamesViewModelFactory @Inject constructor(private val steamAndEpicGamesRepository: SteamAndEpicGamesRepository): ViewModelProvider.Factory {

override fun <T : ViewModel> create(modelClass: Class<T>): T {
    return SteamAndEpicGamesViewModel(steamAndEpicGamesRepository) as T
}
}
```

Comment: Stack trace line numbers being wrong could be an issue with your Proguard configuration.

Comment: @Tenfour04 the file itself is converted from kotlin to java and i don't know why... I have old errors on firebase and they all end with '.kt', The progurad-rules.pro file is empty... All lines in the pro-guard file are the default commented lines

Answer (score 2):

My guess is that it's this line:

```
val percentage = (itemViewModel.x.toDouble() / itemViewModel.y.toDouble()) * 100
```

It tries to do `toDouble()` on a `null` value. So `x` or `y` are `null`.

Comment: It would be helpful if i managed to re-create the error, But the error never happens on real devices... So how did google manage to do that ?

Comment: @YOUSEF-ELSAYED yeah I have no idea, and this answer is also just a guess. I also don't know if it's even possible in your code for `x` or `y` to be `null` or maybe another non-double value. But it might be useful anyway to try to write your code in such a way that it handles values that are not a double correctly, because just 'blindly'  calling `toDouble()` can be unsafe

Comment: they can't be null , if x or y are null the line for 'holder.gameCurrent.text' will cause an error before the 'toDouble()' line

Comment: Unless they are changed on another thread. I don't see anything else that could cause that particular stack trace.

Comment: @Tenfour04 The data comes from the api directly to the recyclerAdapter ... i don't change the data, Do you have any idea where should i start searching to fix this problem ? does it have anything to do with minifyEnabled true?

Comment: You say it comes directly to the recycler adapter, but it's not. It's passing through the x and y properties of your ViewModel. If those x and y properties are changed from multiple threads, it's possible they change from not-null to null in the middle of this function. But that does seem like an unlikely bug because why would you ever change them to null? This doesn't seem like the kind of bug that could be caused by minification, but I suppose it could be indirectly. What are `x` and `y`, anyway? Why store Doubles as strings? Why make them nullable?

Comment: @Tenfour04 they are not nullable and the data comes from the api as a String, I managed to recreate the error By installing a Release APK and as expected the same error happens again... So i added Logs to try and find the specific line for all that and i needed to add 'debuggable true' in the build.gradle so i can see the logs on android studio, Now everything works fine ! i don't understand... I didn't change the code just added logs lines and enabled debugging on the release apk and now everything is working, Is there an explanation ?

Comment: @Tenfour04 the error "NullPointerException" no happens on a different part of the code, So the problem is still there

Comment: @YOUSEF-ELSAYED *"they can't be null , if x or y are null the line for 'holder.gameCurrent.text' will cause an error before the 'toDouble()' line"* - this isn't true, you can pass *null* as a format string argument if it can be converted to the type you've specified in the format string - and it can for `String`s, which `itemViewModel.x` apparently is. It'll just show up as `"null"`. You're getting the NPE because `parseDouble` (via `toDouble`) explicitly throws one if the string is *null*. You'll have to look at why you're getting nulls from the API, and why they're not being caught/handled

Comment: @cactustictacs Sir as i explained the same code with the same data sent or received works fine on the debug version of the app, If i created a Relase version this error happens, and if i enabled debugging for the release version of the app it works find but there's an diffrent null pointer in another part of the app ... So the problem is within ther release build  not the code

Comment: This could be a race condition. When debuggable is on it could be changing timings to make it less likely to lose the race. Hard to say without seeing the ViewModel code and where x and y are being written.

Comment: @YOUSEF-ELSAYED if you're getting null pointer exceptions, it's because you're getting nulls you're not handling properly (like the one in your example code - you're calling `toDouble` on a null). If you think they're "not nullable", but they *are* null, then that's a problem - either you're wrong about the nullability, or there's an issue (e.g. with an API) that you need to resolve. I'm pointing this out because this can create bugs, which maybe only cause problems in certain circumstances - but they're still there. You need to look at *why* you're getting another NPE somewhere else, y'know?

Comment: @Tenfour04 i updated the question with the view model and view model factory, I am using dagger2 maybe that's the cause of the problem ?

Comment: @cactustictacs sir if i used the same exact code with the same exact api on a phone with debug apk and on another phone with release apk, The phone with debug abk will work but the phone with release apk will crash, it can't be a real null pointer exception because of that

Comment: @Tenfour04 i managed to fix the problem by adding 
-keep class com.yousefelsayed.games.model.** { *; }
-keep class com.yousefelsayed.games.viewmodel.** { *; }
to my proguard rules, if you would like to create an answer i will accept it cause you really help me